# What is the proper location for hive-jdbc-__-standalone.jar?

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, hive, bigdata

This guide on setting up hive 0.14:
http://www.ishaanguliani.com/content/hive-0140-setup-ubuntu

suggests that if an error:

```
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-common-0.14.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
```

is encountered the file hive-jdbc-0.14.0-standalone.jar has to be moved out from $HIVE_HOME/lib/

but when I run beeline, it errors because the file is not there:

```
$ $HIVE_HOME/bin/beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
ls: cannot access /usr/local/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-*-standalone.jar: No such file or directory
```

What is the right thing to do?

Comment: The SLF4J warnings are a minor annoyance. Nowadays every Java jerk (and his dog) wants to bundle utility classes in his JAR, so that you get multiple versions of everything in the CLASSPATH. Only SLF4J raises warnings, the rest does not care, that battle has been lost long ago, Maven rules, all Hadoop distributions are a mess. **Bottom line:** just learn to ignore the `multiple SLF4J bindings` messages, just like you ignore ads on web pages.

Answer (score 4):

You can do any of the below  do any of the following

**RCA**: In hive2.1 the hive-jdbc-*-standalone.jar file does not exist in ${HIVE_LIB} but the {$HIVE_HOME}/jdbc directory.

** System Specification **
hive-2.1 binary
java1.8
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)

**Possible Solutions**:

1. Copy the jar file to the directory expected by the script.
   Easy but I don't like keeping multiple files

   `bash# cp ${HIVE_HOME}/jdbc/hive-jdbc-2.1.0-standalone.jar ${HIVE_HOME}/lib/hive-jdbc-2.1.0-standalone.jar`

or

2. Create a link to the jar file in to point to the directory expected by the script
   (My preferred method). 
   `bash# ln -s ${HIVE_HOME}/jdbc/hive-jdbc-2.1.0-standalone.jar  ${HIVE_HOME}/lib/hive-jdbc-2.1.0-standalone.jar`
3. Edit the file ${HIVE_HOME}/bin/ext/beeline.sh

   `bash# vi +27 ${HIVE_HOME}/bin/ext/beeline.sh`

Edit the line

```
jdbcStandaloneJarPath=`ls ${HIVE_LIB}/hive-jdbc-*-standalone.jar`


to

jdbcStandaloneJarPath=`ls ${HIVE_HOME}/jdbc/hive-jdbc-*-standalone.jar`
```